# Equate stack object to another inside an object C++

Tags: c++, initialization

I have two object, call the `A` and `B`
e.g

```
class A {
   private:
     int x; 
     int y;

   public:
     A();
     A(int x, int y);
     void setX(int);
     void setY(int);
};

class B {
   private:
     const A a1;

   public:
     B();
     B(int x, int y) {
       //my problem is here
       A a(x, y);
       this->a1 = a;
     };
};
```

If `B` is initialised with parameters, I want to have `a1` initialised with parameters as well which `B` is initialised with, hence `A(int x, int y)`.

I don't want `a1` initialised in heap.

I currently getting this error

> no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: const Brain = Brain

### Amend

From the answer below by @songyuanyao

```
B::B(int x, int y) : a1(x, y){};
```

it works but I have a different problem now due to my lack of knowledge for `const`. When I call `setX` and `setY` from `A(int x, int y)` like this

```
A::A(int x, int y) {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}

void A::setX(int x) {
    this->x = x;
}

void A::setY(int y) {
    this->y = y;
}
```

it doesn't seem to change the `x` and `y` values/attributes of class `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the `const` data member with [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation). As `const` object, it could be initialized, but can't be assigned; so `this->a1 = a;` doesn't work.

> For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

e.g.

```
B(int x, int y) : a1(x, y) {}
```

Comment: Thank you, please check my amendment to the question

Comment: @SASSY_ROG What do you mean *it doesn't seem to change the `x` and `y` values/attributes of class `A`*?

Comment: `x` and `y` don't change to whatever variables are passed to `B` class constructor e.g `B(4, 5)`

Comment: @SASSY_ROG It should work fine; I tried a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eQYXPTGkuyUvj8vt)